Why a scalar particle with momentum orbit $\mathcal{O}_p$ is irreducible?
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $A$ a finite dimensional vector space. A scalar particle with momentum orbit $\mathcal{O}_p$ is a represenation $T: G\ltimes A\to GL(L^2 (\mathcal{O}_p,\mu,\mathbb{C}))$ defined by $$(T((f,\alpha))\cdot \Psi )(q)=\sqrt{\rho_{f^{-1}}(q)}e^{i\langle q,\alpha\rangle}\Psi (f^{-1}\cdot q).$$
The writer in the thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08526 "BMS particles in three dimensions" page 67 says that $T$ is irreducible by virtue of the fact that the orbit $\mathcal{O}_p$ is a homogeneous space. How can we show that? Is that a theorem?
